# Toast not displaying with bootstrap and vue (not bootstrap-vue)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, twitter-bootstrap-3, toast

I want to toast as notification to my web app with the help of bootstrap 5 and vue 3 and I'm trying to use template code which is given in the bootstrap official documentation but its not working in my code - here is the code

can some one help me, my goal is 'when I click on the button toast should be displayed'

```
export default{
methods:  {
   toast(){var toastTrigger = document.getElementById('liveToastBtn')
var toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('liveToast')
if (toastTrigger) {
  toastTrigger.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastLiveExample)

    toast.show()
  })
}
  }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="liveToastBtn" @click="toast()">Show live toast</button>

<div class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 11">
  <div id="liveToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-header">
      <img src="" class="rounded me-2" alt="">
      <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
      <small>11 mins ago</small>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      Hello, world! This is a toast message.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: What exactly are you seeing happening? Did you debug your code?

Comment: When I click on the button(show toast) nothing happens..